# System.EntryPointNotFoundException CreateActCtx error's

Tags: c#, mono, entrypointnotfoundexcept

I'm trying to make an C# program in mono, so i can port it to Windows, Linux and Mac very easy.

But I've got this error:

```
System.EntryPointNotFoundException has been thrown
CreateActCtx

System.EntryPointNotFoundException: CreateActCtx
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) WebKit.NativeMethods:CreateActCtx (WebKit.NativeMethods/ACTCTX&)
  at WebKit.ActivationContext.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at WebKit.WebKitBrowser..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) WebKit.WebKitBrowser:.ctor ()
  at TW_Overview.globalVars..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Here is some code:

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init ();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow ();
            startUp();
            win.Show ();
            Application.Run ();
        }

        public static globalFunc globalfunctions = new globalFunc();

        public static void startUp ()
        {
            while (!globalfunctions.isLoggedIn()) {
                globalfunctions.showLogin();
            }
        }
```

And here's the globalfunc (part of it)

```
public Boolean isLoggedIn()
        {
            if (globalVars.isLoggedIn == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

The line that give's the error is:

```
while (!globalfunctions.isLoggedIn()) {
```

I've gotten this type of approach in C# Windows Visual Studio, and there it worked. So i don't understand why it isn't working.

Hope that you guys have an clue about what the problem is...

**EDIT 1**

I've downloaded the latest version of webkit.net [link](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/), unpacked it and put all the dllś and folders in the debug folder of my program. I also added an refrence to the dll in the debug folder.

And i've added everywhere this line:

```
using WebKit;
```

So i don't know what the problem is. mayby something with static and not static??? i'm not that good at that part...

**EDIT 2**

The problem is that this isn't supported bij Mono.
After some searching and looking if it's possible to port the webkit to mono, i came across an site that already did that for us.

https://live.gnome.org/WebKitGtk

I cant test it right now, but i think it should work. If not, then i will incontinent searching and update here if i find the solution.

Comment: It looks like an internal PInvoke issue. Do you have the WebKit dependencies?

Comment: @leppie, i've downloaded the latest  webkit.net from sourceforge (WebKit.NET-0.5-bin-cairo). added all the DLL's and maps that are in the bin folder to the debug of my program. And i added an refrence to teh webkitbrowser.dll. But the problem is still there...

Comment: Well, it still isn't compatible with anything but Windows.  It is open source so you can fix the problem yourself.  Don't forget to check your changes back in.

Comment: @HansPassant, damm, i will take a look at it to make it work.. thank you for pointing that out to me...

Comment: @HansPassant, updated the answer, looks like the porting is already done...